# Trouble understanding how graphql data is getting to react component

Tags: graphql, gatsby, ghost-blog

I'm not sure how the react component is getting data from graphql in this library (or in general). I'm looking at https://github.com/TryGhost/gatsby-starter-ghost and in places like src/templates/post.js there is a graph query at the bottom that some how passes the data into the component.

I've looked all around the web for documentation about this but I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplified process (some steps obviously left out) is pretty much to create a `slug` that populates data on a template you develop. More information can be found here:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/

Example:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
export default ({ data }) => {
  const post = data.markdownRemark
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

The query is at the bottom. It looks for the slug then gets the related GraphQL information and populates it on the template "post.js" as an example.